# Is there a way to use spray-route and spray-can together?

Tags: scala, spray

I'm trying to use these two things together. But I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know how to use them together ?

Many thanks

http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/key-concepts/big-picture/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working example here: https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/release/1.2/examples/spray-routing/on-spray-can